# Why Symfony generates route with kernel name?

Tags: symfony, symfony5, symfony-routing

I can't realize, why Symfony generates the route

```
kernel:
    resource: ../../src/Kernel.php
    type: annotation
```

I read documentation
https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#creating-routes-as-attributes-or-annotations

> This command also creates the following configuration file:
>
> ```
> # config/routes/annotations.yaml 
> controllers:
>     resource: ../../src/Controller/
>     type: annotation
>
> kernel:
>     resource: ../../src/Kernel.php
>     type: annotation
> ```
>
> This configuration tells Symfony to look for routes defined as
> annotations in any PHP class stored in the src/Controller/ directory.

But why `kernel:` ? There are no annotations in the Kernel class, i can delete `kernel:` section and have no difference at all, so, what's the point ?

Comment: The [Symfony Slack Channel](https://symfony.com/community) might be a better place for this sort of question.  It's actually possible to make a 'single class' application using just the kernel class.  I always figured the configuration was related to that fact but never bothered to ask.